# Detecting Adblock - DOM Ready not working

Tags: javascript, php, html, dom, browser

While working on adblock extension detection, i noticed that the extension disables DOM ready events like

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );          // DOES NOTHING IF EXTENSION IS INSTALLED
});
```

Since i need to detect changes in DOM after it has loaded completely , what alternative approach can be taken to detect these changes only after the DOM has loaded ?

note - right now i am using `setTimeout` to wait for the DOM load.

Comment: Adblock disabling `document.ready`? I think there must be something else going on here. (`document.ready` works on all my browsers with adblock)
Did you post all relevant code?

Comment: Is there something about adblock actually blocking that script on your domain? I've read about needing sites whitelisted for the .ready() to work before.

Comment: This isnt the relevant code, but just tested, even this does not work.